# C++ Double Linked List Reverse Print

Tags: c++, list

I am trying to write a reverse print function as part of a doubly linked list.  Here are the relevant functions that I have written:

```
void PLAYER::AddNode(int addID, std::string addName){

nodePtr n = new node; //creates a new node pointer
n->next = NULL;       //Make next null
n->prev = NULL;      // this will set this to be the ending node
n->ID = addID;      //These two lines pass the information into the node
n->name = addName;  // ID# and Name Information

if(head != NULL){  // This checks to see if a list is set up.
    curr = head;    // Make this point to the head.
    while(curr->next != NULL){ // Loops through until the NULL is found
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = n; //Make the currnet node point to N
    n->prev = curr; //Make the previous node connect to curr
    n->next = tail; // connect new node to the tail.

}
else{
    head = n;   //If there is no list, this makes N the first node.

}
```

Here is the class that prototypes the functions to be used.

```
class PLAYER
{
public:  // Functions go inside PUBLIC
    PLAYER();
    void AddNode(int addID, std::string addName);
    void DeleteNode(int delPlayer);
    void SortNode();
    void PrintList();
    void InsertHead(int AddID, std::string addName);
    void PrintReverse();

private:  //Variables go into here
   typedef struct node{
            // ...
            std::string name;
            int ID;
            node* next;
            node* prev;
    }* nodePtr;


    nodePtr head, curr, temp, prev, test, tail;


};
```

And finally my attempt to create a reverse traversing function to print backwards.

```
void PLAYER::PrintReverse()
{
    curr = head; 
    while(curr->next != NULL) //Get to the end of the list
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    while(curr->prev != NULL)    //Work backward and print out the contents
    {
        std::cout << curr->ID << " " << curr->name << endl;
        curr = curr->prev;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is inside the PrintReverse() function have it initialize via the tail pointer, however I can not figure out the functions to add to PrintReverse() and to AddNode() in order to have the new nodes pointed to by tail.

This is my first question posting here, I hope I covered all my bases.  Thank you for any help I can find.

EDIT:

Thank you for all your input.  I am relearning data structures and yes this is some self imposed homework on my part to begin to get the logic flowing again.

I will make the changes when I get home tonight.

Comment: There are a couple of problems with your code: (i) Where are you initializing tail? (ii) In the AddNode why not use tail directly rather than iterating till the end, (iii) In the PrintReverse function, you already have tail nodePtr in your class, why not start there?

Comment: Implementing a doubly linked list can be slightly tricky, depending on how much programming experience you have. Why not use the list container from STL?

Comment: @AmmarHussain I think 99% of linked-list questions are homework assignments.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus: True that!

Comment: Off topic: recommend moving the four lines after allocating the `new node` in `AddNode` to a `node` constructor. Makes for cleaner code. `node` should look after `node` and `PLAYER` should look after `PLAYER`. And of course Ape shall not kill Ape.

Comment: Also off topic: `typedef struct` is a left-over from the 70's. You can safely jettison `nodePtr` in favour of `node *`.

Comment: Recommend against having a head and tail be anything other than pointers to the first and last `node`s respectively. `n->next = tail` suggests that `tail` is a placeholder, and this will complicate things. For example, you can't use `tail` to get the end of the list, but if `tail` points to the last `node` and the last `node`'s `next` points to `nullptr`, then you can add a new `node` by `tail->next = n; n->prev = tail; tail = n;` with far less effort.

Answer (score 1):

The following changes would need to be considered.

The `PrintReverse` function would not need the forward pass to obtain the `tail`.

```
void PLAYER::PrintReverse()
{
    curr = tail; 
    while(curr != NULL)    //Work backward and print out the contents
    {
        std::cout << curr->ID << " " << curr->name << endl;
        curr = curr->prev;
    }
}
```

There is a problem in how tail is handled in the `AddNode` function. See the lines where the comments contain `[CHANGED]` and `[ADDED]`:

```
if(head != NULL){  // This checks to see if a list is set up.
    curr = head;    // Make this point to the head.
    while(curr->next != NULL){ // Loops through until the NULL is found
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    curr->next = n; //Make the currnet node point to N
    n->prev = curr; //Make the previous node connect to curr
    n->next = NULL; // [CHANGED]: we want the last node not to have a successor.
}
else{
    head = n;   //If there is no list, this makes N the first node.
}

tail = n;       // [ADDED]: the last node added is the new tail.
```

However, a simpler solution is to avoid again the forward pass, and start from tail.

```
if(tail != NULL){  // This checks to see if a list is set up.
    tail->next = n; //Make the old tail node point to N
    n->prev = tail; 
    n->next = NULL; 
}
else{
    head = n;   //If there is no list, this makes N the first node.
}

tail = n;       // The last node added is the new tail.
```

Comment: In `PrintReverse()`, you should check if `tail` is NULL before looping, in case the list is empty.

Comment: `PrintReverse()` is also skipping the first node in the list. You should be using `while(curr != NULL)` instead of `while(curr->prev != NULL)`

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance!